# apache simple rewrite rule or rewrite condition for query string

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Im trying to add a rewrite rule to my htcaccess file and the part Im having trouble wth is the query string. I want to add the query string parameter pid to the rewrite rule. Both lines of code don't work how do set up query string for you're rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule browse/(.*)/?pid=(/d+) show_products.php?department=$1&pid=$2
RewriteRule browse/(.*)/?pid=([0-9]+) show_products.php?department=$1&pid=$2
```

should look like

```
http://mysite.com/browse/department?pid=1
```

or

```
http://mysite.com/browse/department/?pid=1
```

i've got it to do this but it has no question mark does anyone know how to get it to have the question mark

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule browse/(.*)/pid=([0-9]+)$ show_products.php?department=$1&pid=$2 

http://mysite.com/browse/department/pid=1
```

Comment: Your edit isn't very clear. If you're trying to say that something didn't work, provide an example of what didn't. (hint: question marks in a regex need to be escaped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRules do not directly match query strings.
You need to use something like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule browse/(.*)/ show_products.php?department=$1&pid=%1
```

Not tested but that should be close.

Comment: I tried you're example and it didn't work i've updated my code and I got something close but its not quite exact I want the question mark in there for querying

Comment: @KDM This really isn't how the Q&A system is designed to be used; anyone who comes along and sees this question isn't going to understand what the solution was. Please elaborate on what your final solution was.